# Making a POST request to Web App runs doPost, but getting 400 error in response

Tags: php, wordpress, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, post

#### Scenario:

I have a Wordpress website set up on an AWS server. I'm making a POST request to a Google Apps Script Web App and attempting to log the response. My PHP code is as follows:

```php
$request_obj = array(
    'data' => array(
        'client_id' => $client_id,
        'email' => $email
    )
);

$request_data = json_encode($request_obj);

$url = WEB_APP_URL;

$webSafe = str_replace(['+', '/'], ['-', '_'], base64_encode($request_data));

$args = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'headers' => array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ),
    'body' => array(
        'data' => $webSafe
    )
);

$response = wp_remote_post($url, $args);
```

In my Cloud Logs in GCP, I can see that the request is being received and the doPost function is being run, as per the timestamps and logs of the function

```js
function doPost(e) {

  let request = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)

  request = request.replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/").replace(/%3D/g, "=")
  request = forge.util.decode64(request) 

  console.log("request")
  console.log(request)

  const props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
  props.setProperty(request.clientId, request.email)

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(`{
      "data": "success", 
      "code": 200
    }`).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  
}
```

But the response I'm getting from Apps Script is as if the request I've made in the first place is invalid:

```json
{
   "headers":{
      
   },
   "body":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\n  <meta name=viewport content=\"initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width\">\n  <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1<\/title>\n  <style>\n    {margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px\/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px} > body{background:url(\/\/www.google.com\/images\/errors\/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(\/\/www.google.com\/images\/branding\/googlelogo\/1x\/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(\/\/www.google.com\/images\/branding\/googlelogo\/2x\/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%\/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(\/\/www.google.com\/images\/branding\/googlelogo\/2x\/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(\/\/www.google.com\/images\/branding\/googlelogo\/2x\/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}\n  <\/style>\n  <a href=\/\/www.google.com\/><span id=logo aria-label=Google><\/span><\/a>\n  <p><b>400.<\/b> <ins>That\u2019s an error.<\/ins>\n  <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>That\u2019s all we know.<\/ins>\n",
   "response":{
      "code":400,
      "message":"Bad Request"
   },
   "cookies":[
      
   ],
   "filename":null,
   "http_response":{
      "data":null,
      "headers":null,
      "status":null
   }
}
```

Even though I can see the doPost logs in GCP:

[image]

I have another POST request being made from the Wordpress site, the details of the request are the same except for the request object. The working payload is as such:

```
$request_obj = array(
  'data' => array(
    'nonce' => $nonce,
    'client_name' => $company_name,
    'product' => $payment_data->product_name,
    'license_information' => array(
      'subscription_id' => $license_data->id,
      'end_of_billing_cycle' => $payment_data->current_period_end,
      'last_payment' => $payment_data->current_period_start,
      'product' => $payment_data->product
    )
  )
);
```

#### Question:

Under what circumstances would 400 error be thrown while the doPost still runs? I'm at a bit of a loss because normally the Apps Script code wouldn't run if the HTTP request was invalid.

Comment: First, unfortunately, I cannot test this situation now. I apologize for this situation. From your showing error message, I'm worried about the following specification of the Web Apps. In the current stage, when it requests `doPost`, the redirect occurs. In the 1st request, the POST method is required to be used. At this time, sending the request body is finished. After this, as the 2nd request of the redirect, the GET method is required to be used. In general, I think that the redirect request might use the same POST method. I think that this is different from Web Apps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure about the specification of the redirect of `wp_remote_post`. But, in your situation, the request body of `body` can be correctly pushed. On the other hand, the returned value cannot be correctly retrieved. From this situation, I'm worried about the above specification of the Web Apps. So, in this case, how about manually requesting 2 requests including the redirect using the script? But, I'm not sure whether this is related to the reason for your current issue. So, I posted this as a comment. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your comment. Can you please explain a little more about the redirect, and where the redirect comes from/goes to?

Comment: I can't make sense of what you are doing there. Why are you encoding your data first as JSON, and then that again as Base64? What is the point of that supposed to be?

Comment: AFAIK, `wp_remote_post` has no logic implemented to automatically encode your data according to whatever you might specify as `Content-Type` - so you are likely not eve sending a JSON request here, but data encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: @CBroe There's another place in my code which uses a POST request to the same web app, the only difference being the payload data. I'll add that to my question but I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: The point is, the doPost function runs, and processes the data I send correctly. But for some reason WP is seeing a 400 bad request error from Google regardless.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your question of `Can you please explain a little more about the redirect, and where the redirect comes from/goes to?`, in the case of Web Apps, when it requests the Web Apps URL, the status code 302 is returned. In this case, the retrieved HTML includes the hyperlink of the redirect. When it requests the redirect URL, the returned values are returned from Web Apps. It seems that this is the current specification of Web Apps.

Comment: Here, in the case of `doPost`, first, it is required to request the Web Apps URL with the POST method. And, the redirect URL is returned. The data of the request body of the POST method has already been sent at this time. And, as the next step, when it requests the redirect URL with the GET method, the values are returned from the Web Apps. From your question, I guessed that your issue might be this part. If this explanation and my guess were not useful, I apologize.

Comment: For example, how about the following flow? 1. Run POST request to your Web Apps URL with `'redirection' => 0` using `wp_remote_post`. 2. Retrieve the Location URL (redirect URL) from the response header. 3. Run GET request to the retrieved location URL with `'redirection' => 0` using `wp_remote_get`. By this flow, I guess that the POST request for the Web Apps can be achieved. But, if I misunderstood your current issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by switching to curl and adding an accept header:

```php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json", "accept: application/json"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
  file_put_contents($log_file, 'Error occurred: ' . curl_error($ch), FILE_APPEND);
}

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the code that works using wordpress api as well:

```
$args = array(
    'redirection' => 0,
    'body' => array(
        'data' => $webSafe
    )
);
$response = wp_remote_post($url, $args);    
$headers = wp_remote_retrieve_headers($response);
if (isset($headers['location'])) $response = wp_remote_get($headers['location']);
```

the reason is that `wp_remote_post` handles the `302` redirect returned by script.google.com as if it was `307`, but script.google.com expects it to be handled like a `303` redirect (that is how browsers as well as curl do)